# How to interrupt transformation in Saxon-JS?

Tags: saxon, saxon-js

I am trying to implement a feature to interrupt the file transformation whenever it receives an interrupt message/event. The current solution I am thinking of is to spawn a process that runs the Saxon command line and kill the process whenever required. But I am looking for another solution that uses Saxon-JS instead of the command line.

A similar discussion can be found at: https://saxonica.plan.io/boards/3/topics/731

Comment: You mention the command line so I guess this is in Node.js, not in the browser?

Comment: It would be useful to know more about the requirement. Are you concerned about interrupting badly written / untrusted / unreliable XSLT code? Are you trying to protect against accidental runaway code, or malicious denial-of-service attacks?

Comment: Yes, it is in NodeJS, not in the browser. One aspect is about interrupting the transformation if it takes too long (maybe because of badly written XSLT code), another is just to give users more freedom of control of the service so they are free to interrupt the process.